# C++ Iterating a menu until all choices have been selected

Tags: c++

I am working on my final project for a c++ class. My program is an Inventory-taking console app. So far I have been able to get the program to fully run as intended through each item and each size under the item. I added a menu to the program for the employee to be able to choose which item they want to do inventory for. I would like this menu to keep being displayed until ALL choices (items) have been "accounted for". I did a switch case which works but it does NOT iterate through all items, but instead only through the single item selected. How can I make the menu loop until all items have been accounted for? (as this is the point for doing inventory at a retail store)
here is my code:

```
    //Name: Abdul Tabel
//Inventory program

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 


// clothing item class declaration
class Item
{
    private: 
        double small;
        double medium;
        double large;
    public: 
        void setSmall(double);
        void setMedium(double);
        void setLarge(double);
        double getRem() const;
        double getSmall() const;
        double getMedium() const;
        double getLarge() const;
        double allRem() const;
};

//menu function
void showMenu()
{   
    cout << "Please choose an item from the menu to do inventory for\n Only choose each item one time!";
    cout << "\nType 'A' for Shirts";
    cout << "\nType 'B' for Pants";
    cout << "\nType 'C' Shoes";
    cout << "\nType 'D' to quit the program" << endl;
}

//assign value to small item
void Item::setSmall(double null)
{
    small = null;   
}

//assign value to medium item
void Item::setMedium(double null)
{
    medium = null;  
}

//assign value to large item
void Item::setLarge(double null)
{
    large = null;   
}


//gets value from small variable
double Item::getSmall() const
{
    return small;
}

//gets value from medium variable
double Item::getMedium() const
{
    return medium;
}

//gets value from large variable
double Item::getLarge() const
{
    return large;
}

//gets total of reamining items
double Item::allRem() const
{
    return small + medium + large;
}




int main() 
{ 
    Item shirt;
    Item pants;
    Item shoes;

    double number;
    double totalRemaining;
    char selection;


    // constants for menu choice
    const char choice_a = 'A',
               choice_b = 'B',
               choice_c = 'C',
               quit_choice = 'D';

    // set output format
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    //show menu
    showMenu();
    cin >> selection;

    switch (selection)  // respond to the user's menu selection
    {
        case choice_a: // get shirt item inventory
                    cout << "Enter how many small shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setLarge(number);
            break;

        case choice_b: // get pants item inventory
                    cout << endl << "Enter how many small pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setLarge(number);
            break;

        case choice_c: // get shoes item inventory
                    cout << endl << "Enter how many small shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setLarge(number);
            break;

        case quit_choice:
            cout << "Program ending.\n";
            cin.get(); cin.get(); 
            return 0;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "The valid choices are A through D. Run the\n"
                 << "program again and select one of those.\n";
            cin.get(); cin.get();
            return 0;
    }



    //being displaying inventory results
    cout << endl << "\n*******************";
    cout << endl << "*Inventory results*";
    cout << endl << "*******************" << endl;


    //displays shirt results
    if (shirt.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << shirt.getSmall() << " small shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << shirt.getSmall() << " small shirts left." << endl;  
    if (shirt.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getMedium() << " medium shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getMedium() << " medium shirts left." << endl;
    if (shirt.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getLarge() << " large shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getLarge() << " large shirts left." << endl;

    cout << "There are a total of " << shirt.allRem() << " shirts left." << endl;


    // displays pant results
    if (pants.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << pants.getSmall() << " small pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << pants.getSmall() << " small pants left." << endl;
    if (pants.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << pants.getMedium() << " medium pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << pants.getMedium() << " medium pants left." << endl;
    if (pants.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << pants.getLarge() << " large pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << pants.getLarge() << " large pants left." << endl;
    cout << "There are a total of " << pants.allRem() << " pants left." << endl;



    // displays shoe results
    if (shoes.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << shoes.getSmall() << " small shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << shoes.getSmall() << " small shoes left." << endl;
    if (shoes.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getMedium() << " medium shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getMedium() << " medium shoes left." << endl;
    if (shoes.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getLarge() << " large shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getLarge() << " large shoes left." << endl;
    cout << "There are a total of " << shoes.allRem() << " shoes left." << endl;


    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}


cin.get(); cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

PS: without the switch case, I got the program to successfully iterate through each single item and display all results without any "garbage" results. The garbage results only appeared after I did the switch case, as the inputs only account for one single item.

PSS: I also tried a do while loop enclosing the switch case, but it was not working as intended. I am open to different types of solutions and it does NOT have to end up being switch case, although if there is an easy way to incorporate switch case, it is preferable.
THANK YOU!

EDIT: HERE IS THE CLEAN CODE WITHOUT SWITCH CASE OR MENU

```
    //Name: Abdul Tabel
//Inventory program

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 


// clothing item class declaration
class Item
{
    private: 
        double small;
        double medium;
        double large;
    public: 
        void setSmall(double);
        void setMedium(double);
        void setLarge(double);
        double getRem() const;
        double getSmall() const;
        double getMedium() const;
        double getLarge() const;
        double allRem() const;
};

//menu function
void showMenu()
{   
    cout << "Please enter the items remaining for the following items" << endl;
}

//assign value to small item
void Item::setSmall(double null)
{
    small = null;   
}

//assign value to medium item
void Item::setMedium(double null)
{
    medium = null;  
}

//assign value to large item
void Item::setLarge(double null)
{
    large = null;   
}


//gets value from small variable
double Item::getSmall() const
{
    return small;
}

//gets value from medium variable
double Item::getMedium() const
{
    return medium;
}

//gets value from large variable
double Item::getLarge() const
{
    return large;
}

//gets total of reamining items
double Item::allRem() const
{
    return small + medium + large;
}




int main() 
{ 
    Item shirt;
    Item pants;
    Item shoes;

    double number;
    double totalRemaining;
    char selection;


    // set output format
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    //show menu
    showMenu();

                    cout << "Enter how many small shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large shirts are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shirt.setLarge(number);

                    cout << endl << "Enter how many small pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large pants are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                pants.setLarge(number);

                    cout << endl << "Enter how many small shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setSmall(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many medium shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setMedium(number);
                    cout << "Enter how many large shoes are left? ";
                    cin >> number;
                shoes.setLarge(number);



    //being displaying inventory results
    cout << endl << "\n*******************";
    cout << endl << "*Inventory results*";
    cout << endl << "*******************" << endl;


    //displays shirt results
    if (shirt.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << shirt.getSmall() << " small shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << shirt.getSmall() << " small shirts left." << endl;  
    if (shirt.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getMedium() << " medium shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getMedium() << " medium shirts left." << endl;
    if (shirt.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getLarge() << " large shirts left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shirt.getLarge() << " large shirts left." << endl;

    cout << "There are a total of " << shirt.allRem() << " shirts left." << endl;


    // displays pant results
    if (pants.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << pants.getSmall() << " small pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << pants.getSmall() << " small pants left." << endl;
    if (pants.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << pants.getMedium() << " medium pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << pants.getMedium() << " medium pants left." << endl;
    if (pants.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << pants.getLarge() << " large pants left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << pants.getLarge() << " large pants left." << endl;
    cout << "There are a total of " << pants.allRem() << " pants left." << endl;



    // displays shoe results
    if (shoes.getSmall() < 5)
        cout << endl << "There are " << shoes.getSmall() << " small shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "There are " << shoes.getSmall() << " small shoes left." << endl;
    if (shoes.getMedium() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getMedium() << " medium shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getMedium() << " medium shoes left." << endl;
    if (shoes.getLarge() < 5)
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getLarge() << " large shoes left. ORDER MORE!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "There are " << shoes.getLarge() << " large shoes left." << endl;
    cout << "There are a total of " << shoes.allRem() << " shoes left." << endl;


    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I've posted an Answer to my own question at the bottom. I scrapped the menu idea and went with something else. How do I mark this question as resolved?
Thanks to all that helped!

Comment: you made a mistake during copy-past I think

Answer (score 0):

1. There is copy-paste mistake in your code
2. In the problem description you say "I added a menu to the program for the employee to be able to choose which item they want to do inventory for. I would like this menu to keep being displayed until ALL choices (items) have been accounted for".
   So whats the point to give them a choice to choose which item they would want to do inventory for if they MUST choose all the items before showing the result?
   I suggest you remove the switch case and put the "shirts", "pants" and "shoes" items one by one. There is no need for switch case.

Comment: I fixed my typo in the paste. And at first there was no switch case, it was simply procedural and went down the list until all items were done. I wanted a menu and a selection just as an addition to the working code. Its kind of like if you worked at a retail store and you got to the pants first, instead of say the shirts, you have the option to inventory the first item you are around. It is not necessary but just an additional feature.

Comment: I understand what you want, but since the user MUST choose all the items sometimes before exiting the program, there is no need to complicate things. If you want that much to complicate things, you can achieve what you want by using flags. You could use 4 flags, and loop until the user has chosen all the options (4 flags).

Comment: my project needs to be 250+ lines, I have something like ~200 so i figured an addition of a menu would close the gap for me. I'm not familiar with flags, we haven't covered that in my CS class but I will look it up right now and see how it's done. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could try adding more options like: jackets, socks, shorts ... That could close the gap too :)

Comment: Lol if I can't figure it out I will resort to doing that. I wanted to have a little "variety" as far as code goes instead of copying and pasting the same thing over and over. Good Plan B though, haha!

Answer (score 0):

I've scrapped the whole menu idea and added different loops and methods to make my code longer. I added a class that produces an order to be placed for the missing inventory items.
here is my final project completed. Thank you for all that tried to help!

```
        //Name: Abdul Tabel
    //Inventory program

    #include <iostream> 
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <array>
    #include <list>
    using namespace std; 


    // clothing item class declaration
    class Item
    {
        private: 
            double small;
            double medium;
            double large;
            string description;
        public: 
            void setDescription(string);
            void setSmall(double);
            void setMedium(double);
            void setLarge(double);
            string getDescription() const;
            double getRem() const;
            double getSmall() const;
            double getMedium() const;
            double getLarge() const;
            double allRem() const;
            bool orderMore(int);
            /*Item();*/
    };


    class Order
    {
        private:
            string description;
            string size;
            double qty;
            int OrderNumber;
        public:
            void setDescription(string);
            void setSize(string);
            void setQty(double);
            void setOrderNumber();
            string getDescription() const;
            string getSize() const;
            double getQty() const;
            int getOrderNumber() const;
    };

    //methods for Order class
        string Order::getDescription() const
        {
            return description;
        }

        string Order::getSize() const
        {
            return size;
        }

        double Order::getQty() const
        {
            return qty;
        }

        int Order::getOrderNumber() const
        {
            return OrderNumber;
        }

        void Order::setDescription(string x)
        {
            description = x;
        }

        void Order::setSize(string x)
        {
            size = x;
        }

        void Order::setQty(double x)
        {
            qty = x;  
        }

        void Order::setOrderNumber()
        {
            OrderNumber = (rand() % 900) + 100;
        }

    bool Item::orderMore(int Count)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        if (Count < 5)
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    //menu function
    void showMenu()
    {   
        cout << "Please enter the items remaining for the following items" << endl;
    }

        //assign value to small item
    void Item::setDescription(string x)
    {
        description = x;    
    }

    //assign value to small item
    void Item::setSmall(double number)
    {
        small = number; 
    }

    //assign value to medium item
    void Item::setMedium(double number)
    {
        medium = number;    
    }

    //assign value to large item
    void Item::setLarge(double number)
    {
        large = number; 
    }

    string Item::getDescription() const
    {
        return description;
    }


    //gets value from small variable
    double Item::getSmall() const
    {
        return small;
    }

    //gets value from medium variable
    double Item::getMedium() const
    {
        return medium;
    }

    //gets value from large variable
    double Item::getLarge() const
    {
        return large;
    }

    //gets total of reamining items
    double Item::allRem() const
    {
        return small + medium + large;
    }






    int main() 
    { 
        double number;
        std::array <string,4> itemType = {"shirts", "pants", "shoes", "coats"};

        //dynamic allocation of array size
        Item *items;
        items = new Item[itemType.size()];


        //for loop will iterate through all items in array
        showMenu();
        for(int i=0; i < itemType.size(); i++)
        {
            items[i].setDescription(itemType[i]);
                        cout << "Enter how many small " + itemType[i] + " are left? ";
                        cin >> number;
                        items[i].setSmall(number);
                        cout << "Enter how many medium " + itemType[i] + " are left? ";
                        cin >> number;
                    items[i].setMedium(number);
                        cout << "Enter how many large " + itemType[i] + " are left? ";
                        cin >> number;
                    items[i].setLarge(number);
        }


        //being displaying inventory results
        cout << endl << "\n*******************";
        cout << endl << "*Inventory results*";
        cout << endl << "*******************" << endl;

        // dynamically creates a list for the unknown orders
        list<Order> orders;

        // Output the quantitis entered back to the user and create orders for the ones that need orders.
        for(int i=0; i < itemType.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << endl << "There are " << items[i].getSmall() << " small " << items[i].getDescription() << " left. ";
            if (items[i].orderMore(items[i].getSmall()))
            {
                cout << " Automatically creating order for this product";
                Order m;
                m.setDescription(items[i].getDescription());
                m.setQty(5-items[i].getSmall());
                m.setSize("small");
                m.setOrderNumber();   
                orders.push_front(m);
            }

            cout << endl << "There are " << items[i].getMedium() << " medium " << items[i].getDescription() << " left.";
            if (items[i].orderMore(items[i].getMedium()))
            {
                cout << " Automatically creating order for this product";
                Order m;
                m.setDescription(items[i].getDescription());
                m.setQty(5-items[i].getMedium());
                m.setSize("medium");
                m.setOrderNumber();   
                orders.push_front(m);
            }
            cout << endl << "There are " << items[i].getLarge() << " large " << items[i].getDescription() << " left.";
            if (items[i].orderMore(items[i].getLarge()))
            {
                cout << " Automatically creating order for this product";
                Order m;
                m.setDescription(items[i].getDescription());
                m.setQty(5-items[i].getLarge());
                m.setSize("large");
                m.setOrderNumber();   
                orders.push_front(m);
            }
            cout << endl << "There are " << items[i].allRem() << " total " << items[i].getDescription() << " left." << endl;
        }

        cout << endl << "\n*******************";
        cout << endl << "*  Order results  *";
        cout << endl << "*******************" << endl;

        list<Order>::iterator iter; //iterator is used to iterate through all objects in the list
        // loop for orders
        for (iter = orders.begin(); iter != orders.end(); iter++)
        {           
            cout << endl << "Order placed for " << iter->getQty() << " " << iter->getSize() << " " << iter->getDescription() << " on order number: " << iter->getOrderNumber();
        }

        cin.get(); cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```